# Nginx Content Security Policy not working

Tags: nginx

I am working with Nginx v1.2.9 deployed on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.8 (Tikanga).

I have added the following to the Nginx server block:

```
server {
    ...
    add_header Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only "default-src 'self';  style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' http://onlinegraphiteprod/render/";
}
```

I have checked the syntax: sudo /etc/init.d/nginx test
(This was all OK)

Next, I tried to reload the config: sudo /etc/init.d/nginx reload

The problem is that the change HAS NOT taken effect. I am not sure why this is...can anyone help?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have other `add_header` statements in your configuration? "`add_header` directives are inherited from a previous level only if there are no `add_header` directives defined on the current level." See [this link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header)

Comment: Post complete nginx config and not just part of it